# Angular bootstrapping lost

Tags: angularjs

I am working with an existing application that I would like to add angular to. The application is using a custom proprietary SPA framework + dojo. The application is built with mainly dojo modules and heavily utilizes AMD modules.

I have imported angular in the head with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

I have also added

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<script>
   angular.module('myApp', [])
</script>
```

to my index.html.

I have also tried manually bootstrapping via

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

but still

```
{{1+1}}
```

Does not evaluate. It remains as {{1+1}}

The only way I get get it to (sort of) work is in my partial view (rendered inside body of index.html) and I manually bootstrap the application via

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

But as soon as I leave the page and come back, the bootstrapping is gone. {{1+1}} shows as {{1+1}} not 2. If I run the above code again, I get an error saying document is already bootstrapped.

No errors are thrown in console..

I am not sure what to try next. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the page content dynamic, are the other frameworks adding HTML to the page that has Angular syntax in then you are expecting to be evaluated? If so that is the issue.

Please note that Angular is a fully featured framework and that frameworks generally conflict with each other. For Angular to work you need to add Angular code to the page using Angular APIs, such as ng-include, other directives, or a controller and manually compile the HTML being added.

Answer (score 0):

When is the partial view actually rendered?

Unless you actually pass the partial through Angular's [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service (which happens automatically on bootstrap), Angular can't evaluate the expressions.  So, if you are adding the partial to the DOM **after** the bootstrap, Angular will never process it.

using dojo, you would need to pass the content through the `$parse` service first, i.e.:

```
require(["dojo/html"], function(){
  content = $parse(someAngularContent);
  html.set(node, content);
});
```